# How to get all posts related to a taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy, terms

I have a taxonomy page called `taxonomy-hotels.php` I need to get all posts related to particular `taxonomy-term`. Assume I have a term `5 star hotel` and it has 15 posts. But ony 10 returning/showing.

Pleasa let me know how to get all posts ? Here is my current code.

```
            <?php
                if(have_posts()) :
                    while(have_posts()) : the_post();   
            ?>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="item">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php
                    endwhile;
                endif;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably only set to show 10 posts per page, but your template doesn't have any pagination controls so you can go to the next page. There's a couple of different options (ie. Next/Previous links, or numbered pages). This article covers them:
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/

Comment: I am using wordpress loop and I haven't limit the no of posts to show. You mean to change the loop and pass the arguments right ? Except the code I posted here there is not any argument passing to this.

Answer (score 0):

If you display all post in one page then you can use  `'posts_per_page' => -1` in your query 
OR
If you want to display limited record in one page then you can use wordpress pagination

Comment: I am using wordpress loop, you mean to change the loop and pass the arguments right ?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/pagination/#pagination-within-a-post